# Use python to write the game program, but when the program is running the left and right keys do not respond

Tags: python, pycharm

**there are totally 4 files and 1 bmp picture:**

the practice-1 alien invade.py:

```
import sys

import pygame

from pygame.locals import *

from settings import Settings

from ship import Ship

import readline
import game_functions as gf
#定义游戏
def run_game():
    pygame.init()
    ai_settings=Settings()
    screen=pygame.display.set_mode((ai_settings.screen_width,ai_settings.screen_height))
    pygame.display.set_caption("Alien Invasion")
    ship=Ship(screen)#to create a ship
    bg_color=(230,230,230)#set the background color

#to log the user's action
    while True:
        gf.check_events(ship)
        ship.update()
        gf.update_screen(ai_settings,screen,ship)

run_game()
```

ship.py:

```
import  pygame
class Ship():
    def __init__(self,screen):
        #初始化飞创并设置其位置
        self.screen=screen
        #加载飞船图像并获取外接矩形
        self.image=pygame.image.load('images/ship.bmp')
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        self.screen_rect=screen.get_rect()
        #将每艘飞船放在屏幕中央
        self.rect.centerx=self.screen_rect.centerx
        self.rect.bottom=self.screen_rect.bottom
        self.moving_right=False
        self.moving_left=False
    def update(self):
        if self.moving_right:
            self.rect.centerx+=1
        if self.moving_left:
            self.rect.centerx-=1


    def blitme(self):
        #在指定位置绘制飞船
        self.screen.blit(self.image,self.rect)
```

game_functions.py:

```
import sys,pygame

def check_events(ship):
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            sys.exit()
        elif event.type==pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT():
                #向右移动飞船
                ship.moving_right=True
            elif event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                ship.moving_left=True
        elif event.type==pygame.KEYUP:
                if event.key==pygame.K_RIGHT():
                    ship.moving_right=False
                elif event.key==pygame.K_LEFT:
                    ship.moving_left=False
def update_screen(ai_settings,screen,ship):#进一步简化run_game
    screen.fill(ai_settings.bg_color)  # 每次循环都会重绘屏幕
    ship.blitme()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

settings.py:

```
class Settings():
    def __init__(self):
        self.screen_width=1200
        self.screen_height=800
        self.bg_color=(230,230,230)
```

the bmp picture could be random, and my main question might not be about the code, but the configuration( (on someone else's computer can, so it should be a configuration problem)), my python version is 3.7, and I am really looking for your help, thanks!

Comment: In your keyboard handling, you're checking for `pygame.K_RIGHT()` (with parentheses) and `pygame.K_LEFT` (without parentheses).  I'm not familiar with pygame, so I'm not sure which of those is right - but it certainly cannot be *both of them*.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. And the () is used for a test, but in vain. And my main problem was that these codes could run successfully with others'  pycharm but couldn't with mine : (. So I was wondering if it is about my System Configuration. Anyway, thanks for the comments!

Answer (score 0):

The image is not moving because of these lines

```
     def blitme(self):
        #在指定位置绘制飞船
        self.screen.blit(self.image,self.rect)
```

self.rect is a tuple with four values like this `<rect(0, 0, 16, 16)>` but  `self.screen.blit` which draws the image requires the tuple with only two value that is X co-ordinate, Y co-ordinate. Something like this `self.screen.blit(self.image, (10, 10))`. What you can do is specify the position in which you want to draw image like

```
   self.y = 10
  
   def update(self):
        if self.moving_right:
            self.x+=1
        if self.moving_left:
            self.x-=1


    def blitme(self):
        #在指定位置绘制飞船
        self.screen.blit(self.image,(self.x, self.y))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply ! I have tried your method, but it still can't move. Maybe it's sth about the System Configuration.